# SMTP client connection failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I need to send email from my site by SMTP protocol.
My program code works fine if I set email sender as gmail email, but when I put my hosting configuration as a sender it doesn't work.
I get this response:
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 162.249.5.6:25"

My code is below.

```
 SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("segrad-center.com", 25);
 smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
            {
                UserName = "test@segrad-center.com",
                Password = "123456789segrad"
            };
             smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
             smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
             MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("test@segrad-center.com", "khalilyehia12@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "test";
            mailMessage.Body = "a2hostiong";

            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

You can test this email by this link :

```
https://webmail.segrad-center.com/Mondo/lang/sys/client.aspx?CDT=43435.7142577315
```

Answer (score 0):

Now the code work fine.
I've to upload my project to a2hosting server because I'm using a2hosting server as an email hosting, now everything work fine